# Is there a way to trigger the native ios share function from a ios webview?

Tags: ios, webview, uiwebview, share, sharing

is there a way to trigger the native ios share function from a ios webview?

On Android I'm doing this by using JavaScript Interface and call the share intent. I am wondering can I do the same for my ios app.

Answer (score 1):

Check `UIWebViewDelegate` method named
 `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`. e.g.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
   if ([[request.URL absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"share_url"]) { 
       // Open native share dialog
       return NO;
   }
   return YES;
}
```